# Angularjs : format flag in input does not pass letters to filter method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am currently working on an app using Angularjs and I have a problem with an input I'm trying to format.

I wanted to insert a space every 3 characters in my input value, in live.

Here is what I have.

My input :

```
<input
        ng-if="!$ctrl.disabled"
        ng-pattern="$ctrl.pattern" <!-- value is "^(\\d+|\\s)+$" -->
        ng-model="$ctrl.model"
        id="{{$ctrl.name}}"
        name="{{$ctrl.name}}"
        type="text"
        format="filterNumber"
        ng-required="$ctrl.required"
        ng-attr-placeholder="{{$ctrl.disabled ? undefined : $ctrl.placeHolder}}"
        ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled"
        class="half-content" />

<div ng-show="!$ctrl.disabled && ($ctrl.form.$submitted || $ctrl.form[$ctrl.name].$touched)">
   <div class="error-msg" ng-show="!$ctrl.form[$ctrl.name].$valid">Le format attendu est un nombre entier.</div>
   <div class="error-msg" ng-show="$ctrl.form[$ctrl.name].$error.required">Merci de compléter ce champ.</div>
</div>
```

And my filter :

```
 filters.filter('filterNumber', function () {
   return function (item) {
      if (item) {

              return item.toString().replace(/\B(?=(.{3})+(?!.))/g, " ");
      }
      return ;
  };
});
```

As you can see, I have an ng-pattern flag on my input wich is supposed to verify that the user only types numbers (and the spaces are accepted due to my filter). If not, an error message is displayed.

Currently, my filter is correctly placing the spaces every three characters. The problem is that when the user types in a letter, it does not appear in the field but the ng-pattern sees it and diplays the error message. Even stranger, if the user types two times the exact same letter, it appears in the field.

When searching what was happening (see joined picture), I saw that **when arriving in the filter method, the value of the input did not contain the letters, only the numbers**. So the string returned does not contain the letters either, hence the result.

[value of the field in the filter when debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Edg.png)

So my question is : **why the does string passed to the filter exclude the letters and how to fix it** ?